# Reparent non-modal form to existing application

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

I would like to be able to show a non-modal form in an already existing application.  At the moment I can do something like:

```
myform.ShowDialog(handleToApp);
```

but that will create a modal form parented to the application and what I'm really looking for something that isn't modal so when the form loses focus it won't break the flow of control and pester the user about not being closed.

Does anyone know how or if I can do what I'm looking for?

Comment: @Nathan W : Don't know, I just voted it back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, you have to make a class which looks like this:

```
public class MapinfoWindowHandle : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
    {
        private IntPtr handle;
        public MapinfoWindowHandle(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            handle = hWnd;
        }

        #region IWin32Window Members

        IntPtr System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window.Handle
        {
            get { return handle; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

and then you can do this:

```
IntPtr windowhandle = new IntPtr(hWnd);
MyForm.Show(new MapinfoWindowHandle(windowhandle));
```

Comment: +1 Can't thank you enough for this..i had to do this in ArcMap and it saved my day!!

Answer (score -1):

How about a simple `myForm.Show()`?